# What is $[GF(p^n):GF(p^m)]$ if $m|n$?

Tags: finite-fields

I am tempted to use the formula
\begin{equation}
[GF(p^n):GF(p)] = [GF(p^n):GF(p^m)][GF(p^m):GF(p)]
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
n = [GF(p^n):GF(p^m)]m
\end{equation}
and thus
\begin{equation}
[GF(p^n):GF(p^m)] = \frac{n}{m}
\end{equation}
But I suspect this is too simple to be a proof of this.

Comment: It is this simple, yes.